# Running gulp on project fails because it cannot find an existing file

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js

I'm currently porting a fully working Windows project to an Ubuntu system. After doing the installation of apache/php/mysql/composer/nodejs/nmp I try to run the project. I got the directory where the sources are located (in the web servers location) and I do composer install and the nmp install and they all finish without a flaw. The last step is to call gulp. When I do, I get several of the following errors:

```
gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Browserify Failed!: Cannot find module 
'./components/Colegiados/pagosMatricula/index.vue' from
'/home/web/martilleros/resources/src'
```

However, the files are there at the specified location. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Permissions maybe?

Comment: All files are owned and belong to the group www-data. Should this be something else? gulp is run as root.

Comment: Really that file does exist? Try issuing command `ls /home/web/martilleros/resources/src/components/Colegiados/pagosMatricula/index.vue`